# How to fix problem with website speed (500 records in one page) on Nginx + php-fpm server

Tags: php, nginx, prestashop

I moved me shop to new server and I have problem with loading time. I have 500 products in one page (no pagination), first loading takes about 8 seconds (in old server was 2 sec maximum). Then website works very fast because cache plugin is working.

I have Prestashop 1.7.5.2 with very good cache plugin and two powerful servers:
Only with database: Apache, phpMyAdmin (RAM 60 GB, Processor 16 vCores, SSD)
Nginx, php-fpm 7.2 (RAM 60 GB, Processor 16 vCores, SSD)

Only page with products have this problem. I know, 500 products without pagination is not perfect idea but it have to be like that.
Maybe can be wrong php-fpm config? 
Currently I have this:

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 16
pm.max_requests = 4000
pm.process_idle_timeout = 30s
```

I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: you using mysql? show us your sql query maybe its the one that slow the loading

Comment: Yes, mysql. Database is placed on separate server. It is not query problem because on previous server, the same website was fast. Current server is more powerful. On previous server I had Apache.

Comment: 60 GB RAM?? Seriously??

Comment: Yes. Company which I work for bought those servers in OVH

Comment: As already mentioned the bottleneck is most likely in one or more query necessary to extract all the necessary data. Profile the page execution without cache and  look for slow query. If it is mandatory to have all of these products in the response perhaps single product's details could be fetched asynchronously ( to avoid some slow join )